# How can I config spring security "create-session" with JavaConfig?

Tags: spring-security

It can be done with xml namespace: `<http pattern="/restful/**" create-session="stateless">`.  However, my web application use JavaConfig.  How can I config `"create-session"` with JavaConfig?

Comment: `<http pattern="/restful/**" create-session="stateless">`

Comment: Googling "spring security create session java config" gives me this:  http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do something like following:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
        . // Other configuration
        .sessionManagement()
             .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        . // Other configuration
    // @formatter:on
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very mach!

Comment: If my answer resolve your issue then accept it as the answer.